# Database doesn't connected on production environment

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, production-environment

Setup on production server digitalocean's Ubuntu 18.04

production build - dist
php fpm php7.2 , mysql-server 5.7 , nginx , root@prod

very first I installed mysql-server on Ubuntu droplet according to this website.
https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/installing-mysql-server-on-ubuntu/

root is my username of the droplet and whenever I type `mysql` on the terminal it just promnt without asking any password to mysql shell

in my env.php file I have mentioned my database connection like this

```
<?php
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysql_user = "root";
    $mysql_password = "123qwer";
    $mysql_database = "xp";
    $mysql_port="3306"; 


 $conn = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user,
    $mysql_password, $mysql_database,$mysql_port);


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

after that I deployed my production build to the appropriate nginx serve  root and it's serving my website but when I checked my database connection under inspect browser I can see this error

```
Failed to connect to database: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

but when I try this on my Ubuntu server

ssh root@localhost
, password - 123qwer

this can login to localhost

what is the issue with my website please can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create user for root@localhost in your db and add read/write access to it.

use mysql shell on your server. sudo should be used.
login:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

If will ask for the password.

commands:
you can create or replace if the user does not exists. You can alter it if exists as well if you don't know its password. I guess it exists, so you can skip this step.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE USER 'root'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Add privileges to all database. You can add one specific as well.

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I have Mariadb, can be some diff. You can use this for mysql if the one above doesnt work.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

I can't recall if the mysql daemon should or should not be restarted.

I hope it helps!